Unable to handle window management popup while opening a new window in Selenium
refer the popup image hereWhile automating a test case in Java selenium, I am clicking on a button and it will try to open a new window but here chrome popup -'manage windows for all your displays' is appearing as below given screenshot
To resolve the above issue, I used the below code for the chromeOptions :
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.popups", 0);
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
caps.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
// set ExperimentalOption - prefs
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

I tried by putting all the values 0,1 and 2 but still 'manage windows for all your displays' chrome popup is appearing.
correct me if I did any mistake.
